# How can I learn more about desktop software security and testing?

Tags: security-testing

I am looking for some good resources that I can use to improve my security testing skills, or just even my security analysis skills.

Desktop client applications are the main target for this question.

Comment: Best way would be to get in touch with white hat hackers and learn there methods and working... Learn from them...

Answer (score 3):

Try reading https://security.stackexchange.com/.  It is described as "a question and answer site for Information security professionals".

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, I was facing the same question as you are now, just last year. I`ve managed to get a good entry level sites and am going to list them below. However, the most fun I had was playing with Kali linux, maybe give that a shot as well.

Also, another entry level tool that you can play with(and I highly recommend it) is OWASP Zap - Proxy attack - pretty straight forward to use.

Here is the list:

- http://forums.utest.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1338
- https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/
  -http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/
- https://forums.kali.org/forumdisplay.php?6-Kali-Linux-General-Use
- http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/net-penetration-testing-test-case-cheat-sheet/